# how i upgrade kohana version 2.3.4 to 3.3.2

Tags: kohana

I have project written  on Kohana 2.3.4, this project is still active and time to time there is requirement create whole new feature. Because Kohana 2 is no longer supported and whole application stack is quite less I have invest much times possibilities how to upgrade from Kohana 2 to 3. I already know there has been quite a lot of changes and it isn't simple upgrade, it's more like rewrite of application. the directory structure is also different in kohana 3 from kohana 2.

Does anybody have real experience with upgrading Kohana 2 to 3?

Comment: "Because Kohana 2 is no longer supported" --- kohana 3 is not supported anymore either

Answer (score 0):

Check up this official guide "Upgrading from 2.3.x" for Kohana Framework 3.0 http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/upgrading